# Mysql query get multiple results in one row *EDITED*

Tags: mysql

Unsure exactly how to work title here...

But, Below is a MySQL query I am trying to get working (it is broken)

What I am trying to achieve is the below:

REP=0 im
AS deviceim

and

REP=1 im 
AS replaceim

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.id AS iii, tb2.im as deviceim, (SELECT tb2.im FROM tb2 WHERE tb2.REP LIKE '1' AND tb1.filter IN ('SEPID1','SEPID2'...) ) AS replacementim 
FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.orderid 
AND tb2.REP LIKE '0' WHERE filter IN ('SEPID1','SEPID2'...) 
ORDER BY filter
```

**EDIT with more info as requested**

**Data**

```
Table 1

id  

1

Table 2

id//////orderid//im/////REP

34567//////1///654311////0

63219//////1///827364////1
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
id//deviceim/replacementim

1////654311/////827364
```

PS: I am so so sorry about the formatting!!

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Edited question with example data and wanted output